# Android Image button selector for all buttons BUT different background in normal state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

**daily_event_selector.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <item android:drawable="@drawable/daily_event_selected"
               android:state_pressed="true" />
 This is what I was using for ONE SPECIFIC button but I want to change this for different buttons while using the same selector 
       <-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/daily_event_normal" />-->
    </selector>
```

So I have this selector and I want to use it on all my ImageButtons

P.S.: it's working

But I want to give a different background to each of my ImageButtons in their "normal" state.

I want to use this as a generic selector to have the same effect on all my Buttons while keeping the background different.
But since the selector is only specified (as per my knowledge) as

```
      android:background="@drawable/daily_event_selector"
```

in the **background property**.
So, I can't seem to find a way to add background to the Buttons. 
Any idea?

Comment: is there no smart way to do that? I know I can do that by specifying the normal state. 
Can't the selector be specified in xml orther than background property? @DerGol...lum

Comment: You got that right! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `different selectors` for different buttons.
The selectors will only differ in their `normal` state.

This is the smartest way `I know` to do that.

Another way would be to have only 1 selector, and change it's normal state in Java.
But this would really be `other-than-smart`.
Because you have to do some extra work in code (therefore, eventually slowing down the CPU).